# Multiple string array comparisons

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

I have a main array that contains some strings. For each value of main array, I want to check in subarray with which strings it appeared and how many times. For example, I have following arrays:

> Main input

```
mainArray = {A, B, C, P}

Subarrays
arrayA = {a,c,d,m,o}
arrayB = {b,c,p,q,r}
arrayC = {a,p,q,r,t,e,o}
……………………………
……………………………
arrayN = {a,c,p,n,o}
```

Now I want to check where A,B,C, and P appeared together and how many times. It should generate following output:

```
resultArray = {{a,b,0}{a,c,2}{a,p,1}{b,c,0}{b,p,0}{c,p,2}}
```

Last step would be, how many times each string of main array appeared in subarrays:

> Final output

```
lastArray = A=3,B=0,C=4,P=3
```

I would have thousands of main arrays and thousands of sub arrays. Thus, performance is an issue too :(

Comment: Great! Now, what do you know ? Java or PHP ? What ever language you know and whatever you have tried so far, please share with us.

Comment: I am little better in PHP than Java. However, I think Java could be better for such problems from performance point of view?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use guava libraries [multiset](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained)

Answer (score 0):

Let's stay with standard Java.  Break up the problem into steps.

1. Rename these variables.  mainSet, setA, setB, etc. are really arrays, not sets. Call them candidateStrings, arrayA, arrayB, etc.
2. Rewrite arrayA, arrayB, etc. to items in a List, so you can loop through them.  You'll have a `List<String[]>`, with a new name. I don't know your purpose, so I might call this list `partitions` or `cover`, after the idea of an open cover in topology. Let's use partitions.
3. Convert each partition to `Set<String>`s, so you can use the Java Collections framework. You'll end up with a `List<Set<String>>`.
4. Compute a set of all the 2-element subsets of mainSet.  Incidentally, that's why candidateStrings works better as a `List`.  Use `Set<Set<String>>`, and call it `pairs`
5. For each 2-element subset of mainList, count the number of partitions that contain it, using [Set.containsAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29). Store the count in a new `Map<Set<String>, Integer>`, called `pairCounts`.
6. Your `resultSet` doesn't make that much sense here; what data structure would `{a, b, 0}` be?  Just write a method that formats `pairCounts` for human consumption.
7. Iterate over both `candidateStrings` and `partitions` to compute your `lastSet`, which really should be a `Map<String, Integer>` called `counts`.
8. Write a method to format `counts`.

Now, this may be slow. It will work. You can write tests for each step. Worry about speed once you've written correct code.